# Shiny - Go to another section in same page

Tags: r, shiny, anchor

I am using below code and try to do below action.

1. Click on action button to go to next table. How can I do this?

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(ggplot2)
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
        fluidRow(box(
            actionButton("btn1", "Go to Next Table"),
            tableOutput("tbl1")
        )),
        fluidRow(box(
            tableOutput("tbl2")
        ))
    )
    
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      output$tbl1 <- renderTable(mtcars)
      output$tbl2 <- renderTable(mpg)
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(box(
    actionButton("btn1", "Go to Next Table", 
                 onclick = "location.href='#table2';"),
    tableOutput("tbl1")
  )),
  fluidRow(id = "table2", box(
    tableOutput("tbl2")
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tbl1 <- renderTable(mtcars)
  output$tbl2 <- renderTable(mpg)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've added a unique ID to the location in the UI - here the 2nd `fluidRow`, then added an `onclick` javascript function to the `actionButton` also in the UI. No server function means all the work is done by the user's browser which is handy sometimes.

You can add infinite complexity to the Javascript here to customise it to fit your needs.